# Implement save-dialog in OSX style

Tags: java, macos, look-and-feel, filedialog

I want to implement a save-dialog in my program that looks like this 
[image: the save dialog in pages]

Is there a way to get this in Java using Swing or AWT?

For the open-dialog, I use `java.awt.FileDialog`:

```
public boolean getData() {
    FileDialog chooser = new FileDialog(new JFrame());

    chooser.setVisible(true);
    String chosenDir = chooser.getDirectory();
    String chosenFile = chooser.getFile();
    chooser.dispose();

    if (chosenDir == null || chosenFile == null) {
        return false;
    }

    return getLines(new File(chosenDir+chosenFile));
}
```

This works fine and gives a native look of OS X. But I found no equivalent for a save-dialog.

PS: I don't want to use `javax.swing.JFileChooser`, because it's very ugly and I want to keep the OS X style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [constructor that gets a mode parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html#FileDialog-java.awt.Dialog-java.lang.String-int-), and pass `FileDialog.SAVE`.

```
public FileDialog(...get the parent...,
              "Please select a place to save the file,
              FileDialog.SAVE)
```

Comment: Perfect, that's (almost) exactly what I want! Thumbs up!